# multiplication in C# basic program

Tags: c#

> In the Main function, declare three integer variables (name them arbitrarily) and initialize these variables with values (ideally different). Write a program that computes the following arithmetic expression: Multiply the values of the last two variables and subtract the value of the first variable from the obtained result. Write the arithmetic expression and its result on the screen in a suitable way.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int prvni = 10;
            int druha = 20;
            int treti = 30;
            int vysledek = (treti * druha) - prvni;
            Console.WriteLine("Výsledek: {vysledek}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, you tell us?

Comment: well - what _is_ the problem? what is happening that shouldn't be happening? you have to tell _us_ how we can help. welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The problem is you're missing the `$` from the front of the formatting string which should look like `Console.WriteLine($"Výsledek: {vysledek}");`

Comment: `Console.ReadKey();` missed too. He wouldn't see output, Console would be closed immediately.

Answer (score 1):

String-interpolation in that way requires a `$` (dollar-sign) before the string to specify that you are doing interpolation, so: `Console.WriteLine($"Výsledek: {vysledek}");`

For more examples on string interpolation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

An alternative solution could be to simply concatenate the variable to the string: `Console.WriteLine("Výsledek: " + vysledek);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the varable correctly.
Console.WriteLine("the answer {0}", vysledek);
Take care,
Ori

Comment: String interpolation is simplified version of `string.Format()`, what you recommend.